# Add equation number beside algorithm

Tags: equations, algorithms, algorithm2e

Using package `algorithm2e`.

Want to write the algorithm within an `equation` environment, so that it has an equation number on the right margin.

But I cannot just include it inside there, LaTeX complains (probably because the `algorithm` is not supposed to appear within an equation).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the algorithm *before* the `equation` inside a box, and then use that box as your equation content. There is no official *need* for this, but it may make your code a little cleaner. Alternatively, set the `algorithm` inside an appropriately-sized `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\newsavebox{\algbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\algbox}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
      read current\;
      \eIf{understand}{
        go to next section\;
        current section becomes this one\;
      }{
        go back to the beginning of current section\;
      }
    }
    \caption{How to write algorithms}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{equation}
  \usebox{\algbox}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the `[H]` float specifier. This removes any floating behaviour from the `algorithm` environment and is critical in terms of capturing the algorithm inside a box and/or making it stick where you want it to (like in a specific `equation` environment).

Also note that I've set the algorithm inside a `minipage` that is slightly narrower than the text block width - `0.9\linewidth`. That way it ensures that the equation number will fit next to the algorithm. If you have a wider equation number, you may have to adjust this length.

Comment: It should be easy to build an `algoequation` environment

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Werner's code. I think that one shouldn't try centering the algorithm on the page, but setting it at a fixed distance from the margin (here I set it to zero). Also the input is simplified.

A caption shouldn't be necessary, I believe. Instead, I provided support for a standard `\label` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\algbox}
\newenvironment{algoequation}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\algbox}
  \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
  \setlength{\algomargin}{0pt}% or the margin you want
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
  \let\label\algolabel\gdef\thisalgolabel{}}
 {\end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \begin{equation}
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\thisalgolabel}\relax
  \else
    \label{\thisalgolabel}
  \fi
  \hfilneg\usebox{\algbox}\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
  \end{equation}}
\newcommand{\algolabel}[1]{\gdef\thisalgolabel{#1}}

\begin{document}

Algorithm~\eqref{test} is important.

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{algoequation}\label{test}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
\end{algoequation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Act on the line with `\algoindent` if you want to implement a different distance from the left margin.

The width `0.9\linewidth` should be adjusted depending on the maximum width of the equation numbers.

[image]